# How do I enable auto-login in LightDM?

Tags: configuration, login, lightdm

I want user `foo` to auto-login using LightDM (which has been used by Ubuntu since version 11.10). How would I do that?

Comment: FYI, If you are using home folder encryption, you can't enable auto login.

Comment: I know its slightly off-topic: I want to mention `nodm` is an alternative option which can start an x session for a user on boot with no auth (thinks like the lock screen probably wont work, etc)

Comment: nodm is no longer maintained by anybody.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can do this without editing configuration files: go to System Settings > User accounts, click "Unlock" and enter your password, then click the button next to "Automatic login":

'[image]

Comment: I'm working on Ubuntu 14.04. Here there is no option as "Automatic Login" as shown in your screen shot. Please say how to enable automatic login.

Comment: @Ravi: the option is still there in Ubuntu 14.04 and 14.10. But there's an alternative answer below for enabling this from the lightdm.conf file.

Comment: @Ravi do you have home folder encryption on?

Comment: Looks a little different, but can be found in the same place and works in MATE 18.04

Comment: This does not work for me in Ubuntu 22.  The setting is there exactly as your screenshot shows it, but it doesn't work. Creating the config file as mentioned in the other answers works for me.

Answer (score 95):

An alternative to Alin's answer is to create a file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` and add the following content:

```
[SeatDefaults]
autologin-user=<YOUR USER>
autologin-user-timeout=0
user-session=ubuntu
# Uncomment the following, if running Unity
#greeter-session=unity-greeter
```

Next time you start, auto-login should work like expected.

Comment: Setting autologin-user to your user name is enough for autologin to work.

Comment: On old versions there is a bug, if you set `autologin-user-timeout=0` (or any other value to `autologin-user-timeout`), it's not working ([LP#902852](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/902852), [debian#682473](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=682473).

Comment: @Smile4ever for my setup (debian buster 4.18 + openbox) it didn't work without `autologin-user-timeout=0`.

Comment: To specify a custom autologin-session, use e.g.
autologin-session=openbox

Answer (score 35):

From Ubuntu 14.04 and above create the file:

```
/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/12-autologin.conf
```

and add:

```
[SeatDefaults]
autologin-user=youruser
```

Comment: I had to create this file and all it had was this and worked!

Comment: This worked for me on 64-bit Ubuntu MATE 18.04 LTS (Bionic), as of July 2018, when editing /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/60-lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf file like I did in 16.04 LTS, did no good.

Comment: still works great in Ubuntu 22.04!

Answer (score 18):

You can easily do this with `lightdm-set-defaults` if you'd rather not edit `lightdm.conf` manually:

```
sudo /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-set-defaults --autologin "$USER"
```

It will not set the autologin timeout, but the default for that is 0 in the code anyway, so you don't need to set it.

Comment: This doesn't work in 14.04 LTS as lightdm-set-defaults was removed then so the other methods are better.

Answer (score 8):

```
gksu gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

add lines:

```
autologin-user=username
autologin-user-timeout=0
```

example:

```
[SeatDefaults]

user-session=ubuntu

greeter-session=unity-greeter

autologin-user=alan

autologin-user-timeout=0
```

Answer (score 3):

Open settings, select 'user accounts'. Click the unlock button, then change the Automatic Login switch to "On"

Comment: Thank you Luyang Liu, but this optino is not displayed in User Accounts.

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 18.04 (Xubuntu Minimal Desktop), create `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` and add the following:

```
# /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
[SeatDefaults]
autologin-user=<username>
autologin-user-timeout=0
```

I couldn't get it working through the `lightdm.conf.d` folder.

Comment: Worked on 16.04 as well.

Answer (score 1):

Search for "User Accounts" application.
Select the account you want to autologin
Toggle the Automatic Login switch to On

That should do the work.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that this works for 16.04.
Using your favourite editor, amend `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/60-lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf`.
Add `autologin-user=xxxx` to the file, for example:

```
[Seat:*]
greeter-session=lightdm-gtk-greeter
autologin-user=wmurphy
```

Remember to also set the **Not asked to login** option under **Users and Groups**.

Answer (score 1):

**Ubuntu 20.04**    How To: automatic login of particular user (e.g. server login)

autologin for **Ubuntu 20.04** and **Ubuntu 20.04 LTS** with **XFCE4** this works:

(all as *root* using *sudo*)

0) set display manager to lightdm

```
dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

check settings with

```
lightdm --show-config
```

1) enable **login without password**

under **Users and Groups**

set the **Not asked**  login option for the concerned user.

2) create and edit a new file **/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/01_username.conf**

```
vim /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/01_username.conf
```

and set

```
[SeatDefaults]
autologin-user=username
autologin-user-timeout=0
```

replace "username" according; do NOT set autologin-user-timeout other than 0, does not work!

This solution worked fine with a nearly vanilla installation without gnome and without unity.

Comment: How can step 1) be done?

Comment: Hallo @Paolo, good question, I missed this detail, sorry: Start CLI, invoke "users-admin". This shall start an slightly advanced GUI tool for user admin. "users-admin" should be available for all distros out of the repositories (no dodgy "downlods"). In this GUI for each user there should be a password section. Click on it and look out for some phrase about asking for login passwd. Language dependent. I can not tell you immediately how to resolve this without GUI tool from CLI, should be feasible. Some of the following tipps from other contributors  do describe it.

Answer (score 1):

**For kali-rolling:** *(may work for other kali versions)*

```
sudo sed -i '/^\[Seat:\*\]$/a autologin-user=YOUR_USERNAME\nautologin-user-timeout=0' /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

then create/add yourself to autologin group

```
sudo groupadd -r autologin
sudo gpasswd -a username autologin
```

and reboot.

the command uses a seds insert after regular expression match feature to insert the line needed in the right section, you can alternatively just edit the file and add autologin-user= in the Seat section.

Comment: Does also work with Arch, the user have to be in a group named autologin

Answer (score 0):

I have 12.10 xubuntu.
In users and groups choose your user, and click word "Change..." next to "Password:" 
(it does not look like a button, what might be a bit misleading).
There you can change password, or at the bottom mark "Don't ask for password on login" box.

Hope it works.

Comment: Thank you very much Chris. However, as explained in my question, this solution is not displayed in User Accounts.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered that, I need to have ubuntu-desktop to be install before lightdm could function.  This solved my issue when trying to get lightdm to actually login in without going in loop.

The reason for the system to go in loop may be because lightdm needs the ubuntu desktop before it may work.

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: This is absolutely wrong, since I'm using `lightdm` with `openbox` environment only

Comment: Can you point to a link for how to do this? I had set lightdm.conf user-session=LXDE, then switched that to openbox as per /usr/share/xessions/openbox.desktop, but it keeps starting LXDE.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved it with the following steps:

1. login as root: `sudo su`
2. enter the file:

   ```
   sudo nano /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/60-lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf
   ```
3. at the bottom add:

   ```
   autologin-user=xxxx
   ```
4. save the content of the file then exit and reboot.

This should definitely work.