# How can I enable autologin in ubuntu 11.10 unity

Tags: auto-login

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I enable auto-login with LightDM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51086/how-do-i-enable-auto-login-with-lightdm)

After upgrading from 11.04 the computer always ask for the password. How can I change this back to autologin.