# disabling password

Tags: login, password, gnome-keyring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I enable auto-login in LightDM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51086/how-do-i-enable-auto-login-in-lightdm)

I always annoyed when my new computer is turned on and log in, the problem is when i want to browse are always asked to enter a password, is there any way that I do not need to enter a password every new computer was first turned on? I use ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 3):

You need to **Autologin**.

1) Open the Dash and search for "user accounts"

2) Select your username, click the "Unlock" button and enter your user password, then turn on the "Automatic Login" option

---http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/03/how-to-enable-auto-login-under-ubuntu.html

You will still need to type your password when you are installing programs etc.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please clarify your question, I don't know what is asking for a password or when it is asking for a password.

"When I want to browse are always asked to enter password" is it the browser that is asking for the password, or is it Ubuntu?

Did you set a master password in Firefox, because if you did that could be the password you are being asked for. Disabling the master password resolves that 'issue'.

Comment: sorry I mean "keyring" where every time I log in on ubuntu and running application like empathy, chromium, so he always asked for a password. and I do not like it because it is too bad