# How can I force 10.04 to automatically log me in (non-GUI soltion ideally)?

Tags: 10.04, auto-login

I am trying to get my installation of 10.04 to automatically log me in at start up. I tried to apply this method http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3121 but after creating the script there, I was unable to edit the `/etc/inittab` file as there is not one present. Apparently this is because Ubuntu does not use this method and instead uses 'upstart'. Is there a similar way to auto login with Ubuntu??

Comment: If you are on LightDM then here http://askubuntu.com/a/51087/63025

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the fine manual](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutoLogin), you need to edit `/etc/gdm/custom.conf` in 10.04. If you can live with a GUI solution, then:

1. Load the Gnome Administration utility by clicking on System -> Administration -> Login Screen Settings
2. Unlock the window by hitting the unlock button (you will be asked the administrator password)
3. Enable the checkbox for Log in as *UserName* automatically (Select your User Name from the drop-down list of users)

Comment: how do i do this via script, so I can automate this, thx

Comment: @DhanaKrishnasamy: You cannot have a script log in a user, as scripts are genreally run as your user, which hasn't come up yet as you are not logged in!

Comment: This is what I wanted  (non gui approach) -> http://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login/48327#48327

Comment: @DhanaKrishnasamy: I see. You link explains how to have an application start on login, _not_ how to have the system log in a specific user. This question and answer deal with the later. I'm glad that you found what you are looking for, though!