# no 12.04 login after locking user account setting on autologin

Tags: auto-login

I run 12.04 with gnome-classic. I wanted to get autologin since I am the only user.
I unlocked the user account GUI under settings, switched the slider to ON, then locked
the GIU.  Since then a reboot stops at `stopping system V runlevel compatibility`.

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> then gives me a command-line login.  Typing `startx` starts
Unity instead of Gnome. In that, I cannot unlock the User Accounts GUI under
settings to set the autologin slider back to OFF.

Comment: @Eliah Kagan: Many thanks. I have unset the root password with your command. I am not sure but in all my mucking around before I might also have unlocked it. The [rootsudo link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) is very informative. I wasn't aware of graphical sudo usage. I do understand the Ubuntu sudo philosophy (my earlier Mac did the same). I still wonder what I did wrong in the first place. Shifting the Automatic login slider
to ON in the User Accounts GUI seems to

Comment: I'm glad it's working now, and I don't blame you at all for not wanting to continue messing around with a production machine that you now have working properly.

Answer (score 2):

You can log in on a virtual console (you must be doing that after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> but before running `startx`). So if the problem really is [that you set a blank password for yourself](https://askubuntu.com/a/162582/22949) (as [MeM](https://askubuntu.com/users/76454/mem) suggested), you can fix that easily by running:

```
passwd
```

Then change it to something that's not blank. You'll know it was changed successfully because the new password will work to log on at a virtual console. (You can type `exit` or `logout` to log off, then try logging back on.)

If that doesn't fix the problem, try disabling automatic login by editing `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` with:

```
sudo nano -w /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

**Remove** the text that makes automatic login happen. That text looks like:

> ```
> [SeatDefaults]
> autologin-user=<YOUR USER>
> autologin-user-timeout=0
> user-session=ubuntu
> greeter-session=unity-greeter
> ```

**Source:** [htorque](https://askubuntu.com/users/3037/htorque)'s [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/51087/22949) to [How do I enable auto-login in LightDM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51086/how-do-i-enable-auto-login-in-lightdm)

Comment: Thank you.  I now found the way to unlock the User Accounts GUI in the All Settings GUI.  Earlier, I had indeed tried editing /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf and I had also changed my own user admin account password and added a root account password following the excellent

Comment: http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/resetpassword/  Sorry, am new to this forum and keep hitting return which upsets commenting and 5 min isnt enough.  I then used CNTRL+ALT+F1 to login as root, typed startx, get a fresh Unity screen, opened the All settings / Uer accountsGUI, clikced my own account open, slid the autologin slider to off, rebooted. OK.  Maybe the bug was trying to set the autologin sider to ON in Gnome-classic?  Should I know remove the root password again?  How?

Comment: @Rob If you really did set a password for the root account, you can  [re-disable](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Re-disabling_your_root_account) it with `sudo passwd -dl root`. But you didn't have to do that; if you wanted to run X11 is root (generally *not* recommended), you could have used `sudo startx`. Once you have a GUI, you can run graphical programs in it with `gksu`/`gksudo`. [Here are the details.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo). BTW your psychocats.net link has broken images--[this is the correct link](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/resetpassword).

Answer (score 0):

If it happened because you didn't specify a password for the adm account or set it to not asking for a password on log in, I recomend resetting the password, here is how to do it (either one):

- [How to reset your password in Ubuntu](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/resetpassword)
- [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-root-password)

Then it should work. (Yes this is a lousy bug on Ubuntu, hope they fix it.) If that is not the case, then I don't have a clue either!

Comment: Do you know if this bug has been reported? If so, can you edit your answer to include a link to the bug report? If not, [it should be](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs).

Comment: Thank you.  I now found the solution. Earlier, I had indeed tried editing /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf and I had also changed my own user admin account password and added a root account password following [this excellent recipe](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/resetpasswd). To no avail. I now logged in with CNTRL+ALT+F1 as root with this root passwd, typed startx, got a fresh Unity startup screen, went into the All Settings/User Accounts GUI, clicked my user account open under Other Accounts.  No lock/unlock clicker now.  Shifting autologin to off did the trick.  Maybe bug in Gnome-classic?