# How can I enable autologin for my user account when the option is not there?

Tags: 12.04, auto-login

I'm running a fairly clean install of 12.04. I haven't really installed much software, only VMware tools as I'm running it on a Windows host using VMware workstation.

I am trying to enable automatic login just to save some time more than anything else.

If I go to System Settings > User Accounts I can see my user account in the list but no option to enable automatic login. Even if I unlock it still does not show it.

[image: 1]

If I create a new user account the auto login option is displayed for that user account only. If I assign a password then I can enable the auto login option. As well as a 'Standard' user I also tried creating an 'Administrator' account to see if it would work and it does.

[image: 2]

Any thoughts anyone?

edit:

As a quick test I decided to see if creating a new Administrator account and logging into it would make the auto-login available for my admin account. It does, so I tried unlocking and switching auto-login on.
However when I rebooted it did not auto-login, and just went to the login screen as normal.

Is it a security feature of Ubuntu or something to not allow auto-login for Administrator accounts because of the security risks?

edit2:

If I create a new Administrator account, assign a password and enable auto-login it works as intended. Something else I noticed is that when it carried out the auto-login for the new account it automatically executed /usr/bin/vmware-user which enables VMware tools features like auto-resizing of desktop etc.

This does not get executed automatically when I log in to my original account (I have just always worked around that seemingly separate issue by adding it as a Startup Application). I would guess this means that the real issue is something to do with my user account rather than a problem with lightdm.

edit3:

I have now fixed this. Apparently I have to wait for another 4 hours before I'm allowed to answer my own question because I'm a new user....answer will be posted then.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://askubuntu.com/questions/51086/how-do-i-enable-auto-login-in-lightdm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the cause of this one. I fired up a new blank VM with a view to installing Ubuntu on it and seeing if the issue persisted in a fresh installation.

During the installation process, on the "Who are you?" screen you get the option to "Log in automatically". You also get the option to "Encrypt my home folder".

I have encryption enabled on the original VM. It appears that you cannot use automatic login if you are using home folder encryption. (The installer will not let you select them both together, it automatically deselects the auto login if you select encryption and vice versa).

I found this post about deactivating home folder encryption. http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1134121

From my original account, I did the following:

1. I opened a terminal (Ctrl-Alt-T).
2. I issued `sudo su` to become root.
3. I issued `cp -rp /home/user /home/user.backup` to take an unencrypted copy of the home directory (replacing user with my actual username).

   while doing the copy i received the error message:

   ```
    cp: cannot stat /home/tom/.gvfs': Permission denied
   ```

   I just ignored it. Everything seemed to be copied ok.
4. I issued `gedit /etc/default/grub` so I could comment out the lines

   ```
    GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0

    GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
   ```

   I saved, exited `gedit` and issued `update-grub` to update GRUB.

   I rebooted the VM and selected

   ```
    Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-26-generic-pae (recovery mode)
   ```
5. From the boot menu. When the Recovery Menu appeared I selected "root".
6. From the prompt, I issued `mount -rw -o remount /` to remount the root partition with read/write permissions.
7. I issued `rm -rf /home/user` to delete the home folder (replacing user with my actual username).

   I did not use apt-get to remove ecryptfs-utils as I might want to encrypt the home folder of another user account at a later date.
8. I issued `cp -rp /home/user.backup /home/user` to recreate the home directory from the unencrypted backup (replacing user with my actual username).
9. I issued `rm /home/user/.ecryptfs` and `rm /home/user/.Private` to remove the symlinks (replacing user with my actual username).
10. I issued `rm -r /home/.ecryptfs/user` to remove the encrypted home folder (replacing user with my actual username).
11. I issued `reboot now` to reboot the VM. Doing this returns you to the Recovery Menu; if you wait a few moments it will reboot.

    I selected

    ```
     Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-26-generic-pae
    ```
12. From the boot menu (i.e., to boot normally).
13. Once booted I went into User Accounts. The auto-login option was now available. I unlocked, cleared up the test accounts, enabled auto-login and rebooted. It worked.
14. I used `gedit` to edit /etc/default/grub and return it to normal. (Don't forget to `update-grub` after editing.)

Answer (score 2):

fisrt open `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` (in case you use lightdm as your display manager) then add the following

```
autologin-user=Your User Name    
autologin-user-timeout=0    
user-session=ubuntu    
greeter-session=unity-greeter
```

Now save the file and restart lightdm

```
sudo service lightdm restart
```

Comment: When I opened lightdm.conf it already had the entry in there, presumably from when I enabled auto-login using the newly created Administrator account. I added the autologin-user-timeout=0 line for good measure, but it still just comes to the login screen at boot up.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here (from your screenshot) is that you have created 2 account and both are enabled.  For auto login you should only have one account enabled.

Try to disable one of the accounts and you will see the option to select Auto-logon,

Comment: No, I deleted the test account before creating the new Administrator account that I subsequently used to enable auto-login on my original account. Also, the User Accounts dialog will not let you have auto-login selected for more than one account at a time.

Comment: OK, My answer was based what I saw on the screen shot.  Did you have a look at the "possible duplicate" link provided above?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I think the real issue is probably with the original user account as new accounts behave correctly with auto-login and auto-execution of things like VMware tools, which doesn't happen properly when logging into the original user account. I guess I'll have to reinstall as I don't know where to start looking for problems relating to user accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Open this file with **root**  `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/60-lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf`

Then append the following code:

```
[SeatDefaults]
greeter-session=lightdm-gtk-greeter
autologin-user=username
```

Remember to replace **`username`** with your username.