# 14.04: login loops back on itself - ecryptfs

Tags: mount, 64-bit, login, encryption, ecryptfs

This problem follows on from
[14.04: No Auto login at User Account settings - I am administrator](https://askubuntu.com/questions/558561/14-04-no-auto-login-at-user-account-settings-i-am-administrator) (see all comments)

I tried to remove encryption via this link [How can I enable autologin for my user account when the option is not there?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162722/how-can-i-enable-autologin-for-my-user-account-when-the-option-is-not-there/162871#162871)

but  when I tried:

```
$ mv -rf /home/user
mv: invalid option -- 'r'
```

after that I was getting cannot `remove [etc...] Read Only file system`.

I skipped over what couldn't be done and went straight to trying to `rm /home/user/.ecryptfs`. Finished, rebooted, and now the login screen is stuck on the password login screen

I went here and tried this [Login screen loops unless you login as Guest](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146137/login-screen-loops-unless-you-login-as-guest)

I inputted command `sudo mv .Xauthority .XauthorityBak` which resulted in

```
mv: cannot stat 'X.authority': No such file or directory
```

I tried

```
$ mount -rw -o remount /home/[username]
mount: only root can do that
```

I tried the second answer here [Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

```
$ ls -lah
total 8.OK
dr-x------ 2 [username username] 4.OK Dec 15 2014 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4. OK Dec 15 00:10 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 [username username] 56 Oct 24 15:51 Access-Your-PrivateData.desktop -> /usr/share/ecryptfs-utils/ecryptfs-mount-private.desktop
lrwxrwxrwx 1 [username username] 32 Oct 24 15:51 .Private -> /home/.ecryptfs/[username]/.Private
lrwxrwxrwx 1 [username username] 32 Oct 24 15:51 README.txt -> /usr/share/ecryptfs-utils/ecryptfs-mount-private.txt
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `ls -l  /home/.ecryptfs/[username]/`. On the whole, I think your attempt failed thoroughly. Did you decrypt your home directory before doing the `rm`, `mv`, etc.?

Comment: Is this from a guest terminal, or from the boot shell through which I did the last part?

Comment: in a guest terminal I am **unable to change to root grid: Operation not permitted**, and the output for that command afterwards is **ls: cannot access /home/.ecryptfs/[username]/: No such file or directory**

Comment: Try this command: `su - warwick`, where `warwick` is your username. This will start a shell under your user id. Then try the ls command.

Comment: **setgid: Operation not permitted**

Comment: Press Ctrl-Alt-F1, login using your username/password, then try the command. To make posting the output easier, do: `sudo ls -l /home/.ecryptfs/[username]/ > /tmp/file-list`. Press Ctrl-Alt-F7 to get to the GUI, and from the guest account, get the output of `cat /tmp/file-list`.

Comment: **no such file or directory** (still in shell)

Comment: That does not sound good. And what about `sudo find /home/.ecryptfs`?

Comment: **/home/.ecryptfs**

Comment: Ok, unless you followed the steps in http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1134121 (linked in the original post, I'm afraid you have lost all the data in your home folder. We can create a new home folder, but that's about it.

Comment: Ok. I know when I go into Windows, I can access music because that was on a different partition, but non of the documents I had in the home drive are accessible through Windows, so yeah, I accept that I may have lost it all. I have a backup from 2-3 weeks ago, so lost content not too much of a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since you could not get unencrypted content and the read-only filesystem problem messed up the steps, login to a TTY (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>) using your username and password, and do:

```
sudo mkdir /home/bak
sudo mv $HOME /home/bak
sudo mv /home/.ecryptfs /home/bak
sudo cp -R /etc/skel $HOME
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER $HOME
```

In order, these commands do:

- Make a backup directory
- Move your current home directory to the back up, as well as the `.ecryptfs` folder
- Make a new home folder using the basic profile in `/etc/skel`
- Assign you as the owner of the new home folder.

Now, try logging into the GUI (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F7</kbd>) using your username.

Comment: do I need to reboot into the guest account to do (CtrlAltF1)?

Comment: No, you don't need to reboot.

Comment: Ctrl+Alt+F1 doesn't do anything from within the shell

Comment: Nothing at all? Not even show a black, blank screen?

Comment: Nope! just stays on the command line

Comment: Ok, how about the command `chvt 1`?

Comment: **chvt 1** return to command line **sudo chvt 1** asked for password and then returned to command line

Comment: Do any of the TTYs open (Ctrl-ALt-F2, Ctrl-Alt-F3, .. F6)?

Comment: Ctrl-ALt-F2 worked **warwick-ubuntu login:**

Comment: Good. Login using your username and password and try these commands.

Comment: Brilliant. Ok. I'm now logged in to Warwick and the user accounts has the automatic login option available to switch off. Thanks.