# Can't login after killing X Server with encrypted home directory

Tags: login, lightdm, home-directory, ecryptfs, pam

I have ctrl-alt-backspace enabled to terminate Xorg in an xorg.conf.d file:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier      "Keyboard Defaults"
        MatchIsKeyboard "yes"
        Option          "XkbOptions" "caps:super,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"
EndSection
```

This successfully kills the server and brings me back to the lightdm login screen. But after doing this I can't login anymore. After entering my credentials lightdm goes black for a second and then brings me back to the login screen.

I think the problem might be related to my encrypted home directory. After a reboot, if I login via a virtal console (ctrl-alt-F1) my home directory gets properly decrypted and mounted. If I stay logged in via the virtual console I can kill the X server and still login again in lightdm, presumably because my home directory didn't get unmounted (as I still had an active session open). But if I logout of the virtual console, killing the X server results in me not being able to login via lightdm and if I login using the virtual console my home directory doesn't get automatically unencrypted/mounted. According to the README that I see when my $HOME isn't mounted, I should be able to run `ecryptfs-mount-private`, but when I run that it exits immediately with an exit code of 0 and no error messages and it doesn't mount my home directory.

This is happening on Xubuntu 13.10.

I haven't found anything useful in any logs. Any tips on fixing this or diagnosing the problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like your home directory is not getting unmounted. Do you see any errors in `/var/log/auth.log`? If you kill X, switch to a virtual terminal and login as root, and `ls` your home dir, is it still mounted?

Comment: The home is not mounted, and doesn't get mounted automatically if I login from the virtual terminal.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: Are you logging in with username and password at lightdm screen? If only username, then that explains why lightdm does not unencrypt your home directory, and therefore you cannot log in. But that would mean you cannot log in at all unless you log in into a terminal every time, not only after Ctrl-Alt-Delete. A possibly related question is [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/51086/how-do-i-enable-auto-login-in-lightdm)

Comment: No it was username and password.

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl +Alt +F1 . login there by username and password , then type `sudo service lightdm restart`

Comment: Restarting lightdm doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem, my regular account was stuck in a login loop, but my guest account worked. The reason I couldn't login was because I had ssh'd into my computer and ran a `sudo startx` which changed the ownership of the .Xauthority file in my home directory to root.

A simple fix:

- press `[CTRL] + [ALT] + [F1]` to get to text login.
- run `sudo mv .Xauthority .Xauthority_bak` to disable the root owned .Xauthority
- do a `sudo reboot` to restart.

It will create a new .Xauthority file owned by you and login should work as normal.

Comment: I don't have a root owned .Xauthority so this isn't my problem.