# How to fix graphical auto-login?

Tags: auto-login

I tried to set up auto-login but I still have to login each time when I start up the computer. How can this be changed?

- What if changing the Xubuntu settings (XFCE/System/Users and Groups) doesn't work?
- What are the steps for LightDM-based distros (Xubuntu, Ubuntu Server with XFCE (e.g. Raspberry PI 3), Ubuntu Unity, Ubuntu Mate, Ubuntu Budgie)?
- What are the steps for gdm3-based distros (Ubuntu (GNOME), and Edubuntu)?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**Type in a terminal (e.g. Xubuntu, Ubuntu Server with XCFE (e.g. Raspberry PI 3):**
`sudo -e /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`

(Better than `sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` or `sudo mousepad /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`, see below the reasoning* - **Thank you [red_trumpet](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530072/how-to-auto-login-in-xubuntu/530073?noredirect=1#comment2181116_530073) for the hint**)

**Add these lines to the file:**

> [Seat:*]
> autologin-session=xubuntu
> autologin-user=YourDesiredAutoLoginUserName
> autologin-user-timeout=0

You could use e.g. file /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/autologin-xubuntu.conf, instead, but then you should make sure settings in another file in that directory or in file /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf do not override it.

### For GDM-Users

The config file is located `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` ([according to the other answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1205098/30631), please **vote** Arbuntu's answer up if you found it helpful):

```
sudo -e /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

Uncomment the following lines (delete the `#`) and fill in your user name:

```
# Enabling automatic login
  AutomaticLoginEnable = true
  AutomaticLogin = YourDesiredAutoLoginUserName
```

### Extra:

To remove password **on resume**, right-click the system tray power icon then Preferences. This brings up the XFCE power manager (Alternatively you can navigate to XFCE/Settings/Settings Manager/Power Manager). Click Extended in the left pane. Uncheck Lock screen when going for suspend/hibernate.

The last place is XFCE/System/Users and Groups. If it's set "Password: Asked on login" you can change it, and thereafter, if you logout or switch user, you can get back without entering password.

***Reason for using sudo -e instead of the editor directly:**
sudo -e copies the file with user privileges, and opens it with your preferred editor. After saving, the file gets copied back to the original file. In this way, the editor does not obtain root privileges, which is a security improvement. (And if configured correctly, your preferred editor is chosen automatically, which is quite convenient).

Sources: [lightdm/Read.me](https://github.com/canonical/lightdm/blob/master/README.md#configuration), [Ubuntu Forum](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2206129), [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/356316/how-do-i-disable-the-login-screen-on-xfce)

Comment: Mitch's answer down here was what I've tried, but it didn't work. This trick did, thanks!

Comment: this configuration can be found @ `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/60-xubuntu.conf` today.

Comment: @Blauhirn that is the system provided configuration; system administrators must not modify that.

Comment: @Blauhirn see the [README](https://github.com/canonical/lightdm/blob/master/README.md)

Comment: Better use `sudo -e /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` instead of `sudo $EDITOR`.

Comment: @Filbuntu AFAIU, `sudo -e` copies the file with user privileges, and opens it with your preferred editor. After saving, the file gets copied back to the original file. In this way, the editor does not obtain root privileges, which is a security improvement. (And if configured correctly, your preferred editor is chosen automatically, which is quite convenient).

Comment: work for me on a Raspberry PI 3 with Ubuntu server 20.04 and XFCE, thanks.

Answer (score 22):

Click on Settings --> Users and Groups

[image]

Next to Password, click on Change

[image]

Click on Don't ask for password on login

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed instructions. Somehow this does not work for me. I checked/unchecked and restarted the system several times, but the login screen would still appear. The solution with editing the 10-xubuntu.conf file worked, though.

Comment: This only removes the need to type a password - it does not enable automatic login.

Answer (score 16):

Things appear to have changed a bit since the accepted answer was written. Under Xubuntu 16.04 the settings have moved to

```
/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

and they look like this

```
[Seat:*]
autologin-guest=false
autologin-user=gord
autologin-user-timeout=0
```

Comment: on xubuntu-installed-lightdm on 18.04, the file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` does not exist, but if you just copypaste the code to `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/autologin.conf` (or call it whatever you want .conf), that worked for me :)

Comment: Or just create the file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`

Answer (score 2):

In Ubuntu 20.04 with Xubuntu Minimal Desktop

Open a terminal and paste this, it is the same route that you have put @phil294 in an answer above

```
sudo nano /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/60-xubuntu.conf
```

We will find these lines

```
[Seat:*]
user-session=xubuntu
```

You just have to paste this autologin with your username (in lowercase)

```
autologin-user=username
```

It will look like this

```
[Seat:*]
user-session=xubuntu
autologin-user=username
```

To save in the nano editor

Ctrl + o ==> Enter

To exit the editor

Ctrl + x

The next time you log in, the LightDM window will no longer appear

Comment: working on XUbuntu 21.10

Answer (score 2):

After following @Filbuntu's answer, I had to do two more things to make this work.

First, I thought the `autologin-session` parameter was just an alias name so I just put `xubuntu`, but turns out it should be a valid xsession name. You can see the ones available as files inside `/usr/share/xsessions`. The session name should be the filename without the `.desktop` part. In my case I had the following files inside `/usr/share/xsessions`:

```
~$ ls -1 /usr/share/xsessions/
ubuntu.desktop
xfce.desktop
```

My `lightdm.conf` file ended up like this:

```
[Seat:*]
autologin-session=xfce
autologin-user=foobar
autologin-user-timeout=0
```

The second thing, I am not sure if it is required or not, but I looked in LightDM's logs (`journalctl -u lightdm`) and saw the following line:

```
pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "foo"
```

So to fix it I added my user to this group:

```
usermod -aG nopasswdlogin foo
```

Now autologin works as expected.

Comment: Most detailed answer here.
Thanks for explaining how to list the values accepted by "autologin-session".

Answer (score 0):

I'm using xubuntu with GDM so the config file is located below

```
/etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

Find out below lines then uncomment them and fill out your user name

```
# Enabling automatic login
  AutomaticLoginEnable = true
  AutomaticLogin = YourDesiredAutoLoginUserName
```

Answer (score 0):

Mine is a GUI answer to the Auto Login question.

The sequence is Settings/Details/Users.

To get into Settings, click in the top right corner of your screen.  A small box will open with three icons across the bottom.

Settings is on the left, it resembles a mosquito but is actually a crossed wrench and screwdriver.

When Settings opens you might be anywhere in the system.  Look at the top.  If it doesn't say Settings, click on the Left Arrow (<) in the top left of the screen.  That will take you to Settings.  Details is at the bottom of the left hand column.  Users is the third option down.  To make any changes you need to Unlock the screen by clicking on the Unlock button in the top right corner, enter your password to enable changes.  You can add Users, change the password, and turn Auto Login ON or Off.

Answer (score 0):

auto login is described here:

- official documentation  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM
- [How do I enable auto-login in LightDM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51086/how-do-i-enable-auto-login-in-lightdm/1230707#1230707)

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to the question but related for folks in this thread: if you want to turn this OFF: make a backup of lightdm.conf, then change lightdm.conf to:

```
[SeatDefaults]
autologin-guest=false
autologin-user=
autologin-user-timeout=0
autologin-session=
```

Why this can't be in the GUI, I don't know.