# How to log in automatically in Xubuntu 15.10?

Tags: xubuntu, login, 15.10, lightdm

I'm struggling in my Xubuntu 15.10 installation to let my user automatically log in each time. I've found two interesting threads so far, but the are referring to older versions of Xubuntu, the lightdm.conf file is not in the place mentionned so i cannot edit it. The two sites are: 
 [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2206129) & [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530072/how-to-auto-login-in-xubuntu). Probably, the answer to my question is to find the lightdm.conf file, but as this user mentions in 15.10 the configuration for lightdm is scattered all over the root: [unixstackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/246858/lightdm-greeter-simple-prompt-xubuntu-15-10)

Could someone help me please?

Comment: Try looking for /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/10-xubuntu.conf, or create /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf if it's not there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mikewhatever's suggestion was right: i created lightdm.conf with username to log in automatically. Here is the code:

```
gksu mousepad /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Paste following code in mousepad:

```
[SeatDefaults]
user-session=xubuntu
autologin-user=/usernametologin/
```

Then save and reboot. Next time xubuntu will go directly to your desktop without greeting screen.