# Xubuntu 16.04 boot

Tags: boot, 16.04, xubuntu

When I boot up the screen, all I see is a "Guest session" with the message about work not being saved etc. I have to log out and back in as myself. I have followed all the standard answers to remove guest account, but there is no change.

Comment: Can you not change to your own user at the greeter? No need to remove guest account. http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-3LMY7ncI7Kw/VDaIgRGmpoI/AAAAAAAAUic/djuRFzArUd4/s1600/xubuntu1404-lightdm-gtk-greeter.png (just one that popped in Google).

Comment: I can change to my own user, I just don't want to! I would prefer to just see my own desktop when I log in.

Comment: Although not recommended you can set automatic login to your user if you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to auto-login in Xubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/530072/how-to-auto-login-in-xubuntu)

Comment: None of this has made any change. I did notice that I have another lightdm in  /usr/share/. Is that normal?

Comment: I found a file, etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf  contained the line " autologin- guest=true"  I changed to False and solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

**OP's answer**

I found a file, `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` contained the line " autologin- guest=true" I changed to False and solved the problem.