# How do I make Ubuntu studio auto login?

Tags: 18.04, ubuntu-studio, auto-login

I have have set Ubuntu studio 18.04 to not ask for a password at login, but I still have click the login button to get started.

How do I get Ubuntu Studio to auto login and go straight to the desktop on startup?

Comment: Did you do it like this: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/user-autologin.html.en

Comment: The desktop environment in Ubuntu Studio is Xfce, the same one used in Xubuntu. This answer should do the trick: https://askubuntu.com/questions/530072/how-to-auto-login-in-xubuntu Just be sure to edit the session name to "ubuntustudio" as opposed to Xubuntu, and you're all set.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer wasn't quite correct. The file to edit is `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/60-ubuntustudio.conf`.

I added the following to the file as Mook765 sugested:

```
[Seat:*]
autologin-guest=false
autologin-user=yourusername
autologin-user-timeout=0
```

I had to use sudo nautilus to gain root privileges.
Now working as I'd like.

Comment: It would be nice to see what changes you made to this file, could you please add this information to your answer?

Comment: Apologies. I just edited my post.

Comment: My answer should work as well, I selected the option to automatically login during installation. I guess the file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` didn't exist in your installation, so you edited `/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/60-ubuntustudio.conf` instead and that works too.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the file `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` (if the file doesn't exist, create it), it should look like this:

```
[Seat:*]
autologin-guest=false
autologin-user=yourusername
autologin-user-timeout=0
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do one more thing, namely comment out everything in

```
/usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/60-lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf
```

This was painting the login dialog, leaving me with a box to click to continue. When I commented this out, the auto-login went to the application specified in my startup settings.