# Automatic Login Not Working

Tags: login, password

As the title says, automatic login is not working. I've tried a few things, turning it off and on, changing the password, and restarting the system. I always get asked for a password on login however, and with a forced long password it gets *abit* annoying to have to type it in every time I need to log in.

Output of `lsb_release -a`

```
No LSB modules are avalible.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release: 22.04
Codename: jammy
```

EDIT: It seems that automatic login is configured correctly in accordance with GDM3, however it is simply refuseing to work.

Comment: You're missing some key details; you've told us your release (22.04) but not if this is a Server? Desktop? *flavor*? and what DM or display-manager you're using, as autologin relates mostly to the DM being used.   Also please confirm if it's your password you're being asked for, and not a password to unlock your keyring.

Comment: As far as I can tell the flavor is "Jammy Jellyfish", this is a desktop system, I do not have a keyring configured, and as far as I can tell, the display manager is /usr/sbin/gdm3

Comment: *jammy* is a codename (*jellyfish* a second part of that codename); you're likely using Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 LTS (*the desktop the missing bit from above*), no *flavor* (*which would be something like Xubuntu, Lubuntu, Kubuntu, Ubuntu-MATE etc which will report identically as you provided*). If you changed your password after installing; the keyring may NOT auto-unlock on auto-login (*keyring is autoconfigured using your original password given at install*).  The greeter (GDM3) is what you see before you login, keyring maybe asked post-login (desktop will be visible & password asked by apps)

Comment: Alright. Yes I can confirm I am running no flavor. (Standard ubuntu) And yes it is asking for my password and not my keyring as it responds to me changing my user-password, unlike what the keyring seems to do according to a quick google search. From what you have told me the issue now seems to lie within GDM3. Do I change the display-manager now? Or can I change something within GDM3 to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to auto-login in Xubuntu or Ubuntu Server with XFCE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/530072/how-to-auto-login-in-xubuntu-or-ubuntu-server-with-xfce)

Comment: My linked question might say Xubuntu/XFCE, but scroll down and there is a gdm3 part. Does it work?

Comment: There may be repercussions from switching but it works in lightdm.

Comment: Does enabling timed login instead with the delay set to a low value work?

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu (gnome)
Edit the file

> /etc/gdm3/custom.conf

In [daemon] add:

> AutomaticLogginEnable=True AutomaticLoggin=username

Replace username by the right
Save and reboot

For Ubuntu Mate, Ubuntu Budgie
Edit

> /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

In [Seat:*] add:

> autologin-user=username

Replace username by the right
Save and reboot

Comment: Hello! Unfortunately it seems that automatic login is in fact correctly configured in GDM3 as in accordance to this answer, however it is just refuseing to work.