# Can't log into my session even in recovery mode

Tags: password, session

I've recovered my session password in recovery mode
(By doing

1. enter recovery mode
2. loadkeys fr
3. mount -o rw,remount /
4. passwd me
5. wrote password in a paper

)

But when I restart the computer, entering the right password, I still can't login.

What's the simplest solution ?

---

I've also tried to run xinit from recovery, but it is for shells, not for sessions. What command man page should I read then ?

Comment: You want to reset your password?

Comment: No, the system is having trouble keeping the stored password on boot up

Comment: Try setting password-less automatic login through `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`. That way at least you are gonna have access to your system and files. Here is more info http://askubuntu.com/a/51087/295286

Comment: Does the new password work in a TTY (tty2 for example can be opened with 'Ctrl'+'Alt'+F2)? Also, I have has previous issues with lightdm using the wrong keyboard layout so it thinks I have mistyped the password, so checking what keyboard layout etc is in use might help

Comment: Solved my problem : In recovery mode I forgot to activate the num pad !!!