# Ubuntu server 16 add gui and start on boot

Tags: server

I installed Ubuntu server 16, xorg, xfce4
I want the gui will start on boot in user permissions, for the moment i can run xorg only as a root, how can I automatically run xorg & xfce as a user on boot time
Thank's
Stevie

Answer (score 0):

You need a display manager:
`sudo apt-get install lightdm-gtk-greeter`
`sudo apt-get install lightdm` (first install lightdm-gtk-greeter or it will install unity-greeter as recommended package).
Then you can enable auto-login by adding:

> `autologin-user=<YOUR USER>`
>   `autologin-user-timeout=0`

to the `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` file as described here: [How do I enable auto-login in LightDM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51086/how-do-i-enable-auto-login-in-lightdm)