# How do I make Ubuntu 16.04 not ask me for my password?

Tags: 16.04, password, startup, auto-login

How do I make Ubuntu 16.04 not ask me for my password? I have turned on and off the autologin on my user on System Settings > User Accounts (the only user) but it stills ask me for password on the startup.

Ubuntu was not asking for password at startup until I upgraded from 14.04 to 16.04.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: When does it ask? Is this only about logging in the first time or do you also mean at other times suc as when running `sudo`? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

...and add the following lines:

```
[SeatDefaults]
autologin-user=userName
autologin-user-timeout=0
user-session=ubuntu
greeter-session=unity-greeter
```

...replacing `userName` with your user name.

You could also check out [this post.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51086/how-do-i-enable-auto-login-in-lightdm)