# Login programmatically after waking up

Tags: login, suspend

My scenario is that I wish to use `rtcwake -m no` to wake up my computer while I'm asleep and use `systemd/systemd-suspend` scripts to trigger `smplayer` to wake me up with a queue of podcasts.

My difficulty is that `smplayer` can't run on wake up because Ubuntu loads the login screen and is waiting for a login. Is there a way that I can login programmatically? If not, can I somehow run a GUI program such as `smplayer` as root user *while* the login screen is displayed? (So far, it's not working out that way.)

(I don't wish to suspend the computer to a simple sleep, thereby never logging out, because I don't want to have to know in advance when I suspend/sleep my computer that I'm doing so for the last time of the day. To be clear, I don't want to automatically login in all cases, only when the computer is awakened for this purpose.)

I'm on LTS 16.

Comment: You can simply disable the login prompt all together.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I enable auto-login in LightDM?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/51086/how-do-i-enable-auto-login-in-lightdm)

Comment: Thanks, but I really don't want to auto-login in any other case, only in the event of waking from rtcwake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `xdotool` to login, but there are a few things to keep in mind:

1. In order to have the login screen's window selected for xdotool, you need to set the `XAUTHORITY` variable to the `.Xauthority` file that corresponds to your user (usually `/home/myuser/.Xauthority`. Also set the `DISPLAY` variable. See code sample below.
2. Run `xdotool` as the user who is to login. (Your script will run as root. Actually it will run as your logged-in user under some circumstances, such as causing sleep by `/lib/systemd/systemd-sleep suspend`, but under ordinary circumstances, i.e. `systemctl suspend`, it will run as root.)
3. To make this only fire when your alarm is the cause of your wakeup, make use of the `linux/rtc.h` API to compare the machine's current time (`RTC_RD_TIME`) to the alarm time (`RTC_ALM_READ`) ON `/dev/rtc0`. If they are near together when your script in `systemd/system-sleep` runs, then you may surmise that this is an alarm-triggered wakeup.

Sample code:

```
#!/bin/sh
# /lib/systemd/system-sleep/myscript
# PW64 is a variable holding a base64-encoded password

if [ post = $1 ] && [ suspend = $2 ] && [ $(whoami) = root ]; then
  if get_alm_time 10; then # this is an external program you should write to compare RTC_RD_TIME TO RTC_ALM_TIME
    export XAUTHORITY=/home/mysuer/.Xauthority
    export DISPLAY=:0
    su -c "xdotool type $(printf $PW64 | base64 -d)" myuser &&\
    su -c 'xdotool key Return' myuser &&\
    su -c 'bash my-other-script.sh' myuser
  fi
fi
```