# log-in problem on ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, raspberrypi

I'm running ubuntu mate on raspberry pi3. when I try to run my pi from my computer by entering its IP to the "remote desktop connection" it won't work unless I connect my pi to a mouse and HDMI cable and hit the "log-in" button that appears on startup.

please how can I remove this log-in on startup??

[image: Log-in]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without editing configuration files: go to System Settings > User accounts, click "Unlock" and enter your password, then click the button next to "Automatic login":

'[image]

Got this from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/60264/358665) by [Alin Andrei](https://askubuntu.com/users/662/alin-andrei)

Comment: your answer didn't help, but I found other answers in the post you referred to that solved the problem for me, thank you very much

Comment: @SHShaHad ok, so it's good anyway. You can just answer your own question. Might also help others! (I'd also like to see the solution)

Comment: I managed to solve this issue with the following steps:   1-login as root: sudo su
2-enter the file:
sudo nano /usr/share/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/60-lightdm-gtk-greeter.conf
3-at the bottom add:
autologin-user=xxxx
4-save the content of the file then exit and reboot.