# How can I make it login automatic in a preseed.cfg

Tags: preseed, auto-login

All

I want to make my ubuntu 16.04 login automatic after boot up. And I install the ubuntu with a preseed.cfg, I try

```
d-i passwd/auto-login boolean true
```

But it do not work, Do I missing anything?
Thanks.

Comment: The `preseed.cfg` is used for the installer.  If Ubuntu is installed on your system, please see:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/51086/how-do-i-enable-auto-login-in-lightdm

Comment: Hi, Terrance. I read the thread, Is there any way to put this setting in a preseed.cfg so it can auto login after installed

Comment: I am not aware of the preseed.cfg being used after Ubuntu is installed.   See:  https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/s390x/apbs02.html  If you want automatic login you're going to have to setup either the LightDM or GDM or whatever Desktop Manager you have installed to allow for automatic login.