# Automatic Login "ON" but login screen persists on startup Linux Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, login-screen, auto-login

I am trying to enable automatic log-in on a linux PC that starts a QT application on startup.  There is only one user account on the machine, and I have Automatic Login "ON" in the user settings.  Screen Lock is "OFF" in Privacy settings.

However, when the computer is started, a lock screen still appears where I select the user, which brings up the password entry screen.  Once the password is entered, my QT application starts up.

I want to disable the login screen so that when the computer is started, the QT application comes up immediately.  The monitor is a touch screen, so by disabling the password entry screen, there will be no need for a keyboard.  Any help is appreciated, and please let me know if I can provide more information.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Edit `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` and add the following:

```
[SeatDefaults]
autologin-user=<YOUR USER>
autologin-user-timeout=0
user-session=ubuntu
# Uncomment the following, if running Unity
#greeter-session=unity-greeter
```

Suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/51087/925971)

You could also check if with switching to gdm3 autologin works:

```
sudo apt install gdm3
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm not with the PC at the moment so will have to follow up with you on Thursday when I can test it.

Comment: I was just checking a linux PC I am currently using (not the one I am having trouble with) and it does not have a /lightdm directory.  I found this potential solution: https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/login-automatic.html.en

Does this seem like a valid method to try?